# Getting information from a MySQL database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using PHP (with PDO) but I'm not that familiar with PHP so I'm a little stuck.  I'm trying to search one of my databases for all occurrences of $userid and then store the $crn associated with it in an array but I don't really know how to go about that.  Here's what I have so far...

```
$sthandler = $conn->prepare('SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid=' . $userid);
    $sthandler->execute(array('username'));

    if($sthandler->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        // User exists, get user's courses from database and returns array of CRNs
        for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            $sthandler = $conn->prepare('SELECT crn FROM usercourses WHERE userid=' . $userid);
            $sthandler->execute(array($USER => $crnArray));
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to check the documentation on [PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.pdo.php) and [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.pdostatement.php) for more detailed information.

I guess you're already connected to your database through PDO ? (else see PDO::__construct())

With a prepared query you better "bind" ($sthandler->bindParam()) your parameters instead of concatenating them, like so

```
$sthandler = $conn->prepare('SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid= :user_id');
$sthandler->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

I don't quite understand the rest of your code though. Maybe isn't it complete. You make a loop on something that is supposed to always be a unique result (i hope for you, "userid" is a unique primary key).

If this loop is actually useless, then maybe you should consider making only 1 query to get both user and courses at the same time, by using a join between the tables :

```
SELECT u.userid, c.crn FROM users u INNER JOIN usercourses c ON u.userid = c.userid WHERE u.userid= :user_id
```

And from this result, get anything you want. Yes you will have duplicated data in your result (userid on each row of different courses), but it's still a better way than doing 2 seperate queries.

Consider using `$sthandler->fetch()` or `$sthandler->fetchAll()` to get every results and organize them into an array, as it suits you :

```
$rows = $sthandler->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // FETCH_ASSOC will return the results as array with columns' name as keys.
// Do your loop on the array $rows to process it
```

Or

```
while( $row = $sthandler->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
     // do whatever you like with each row
}
```

Also take Darren's advice to wrap your PDO queries with `try/catch` to avoid any errors.

Comment: The userid is not the unique key, the crn (which is an integer) is.  The way I wrote it is all wrong, I'm sure.  But what I'm trying to do is find every occurence of userid, then add the crn to an array (which is what the for loop is for)

Comment: @michaelavena well, what is your way of identifying a user then ? use it to identify the courses then. My join request will do the same as you want to do anyway, but more simply (just one request, one loop)

Answer (score 1):

The point of PDO is to prevent concatenating the query string like you're currently doing. It's supposed to be used used to prepare the statements.

```
$sthandler = $conn->prepare('SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid= :user_id');
if($sthandler->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id))) {
    if($sthandler->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        // User exists, get user's courses from database and returns array of CRNs
        for(int $i = 0; $i < rowCount; $i++)
        {
            $sthandler = $conn->prepare('SELECT crn FROM usercourses WHERE userid= :user_id';
            $sthandler->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id));
        }            
    }
}
```

You're trying to execute with random data in the arrays.

One more thing, you should wrap your queries in a `try/catch` statement, to handle any potential errors:

```
try {
    // run query and all
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    // echo out the error if there is one.
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

And the last note, while you're at it. You should explicitly turn on errors when constructing your PDO object!

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)` the `i`'s are treated as constants. Pretty sure there should be `$` for those.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good spot! It's too early for me here!

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm sure there are more issues around haha, running on 3 hours sleep isn't fun :D